# Create and fill columns in a dataset with data in rows from a different dataset

Tags: r, tidyr

I have DATASET1 with three main columns: country, ID (of political parties) and ideology (a measurement of political position in a 0-10 scale). Each row is a different political party amongst a given country.

I need to transfer this data to DATASET2, where each row is a country (in fact, the real data I am working with has thousands of rows for each country, representing interviewees in a public opinion survey, but I have grouped it into country-level data to make it easier to work with and solve this problem).  In this dataset I have some groups of columns with data related to the most important political parties of each country - PARTY A, PARTY B, PARTY C, etc. One of these groups of columns has the same ID as in the other dataset, so we can use it to match data from this other dataset.

The output I want: columns with "ideology" of each party corresponding to PARTY A, B, etc. but also for the other parties that are not contemplated in the dataset 2 (something like "ideology_otherparty_1", "ideology_otherparty_2", etc.)

I am trying to find a way of doing this using TIDYR functions like *gather* and *spread* together with other functions like "match" or "case_when to match PARTY_A, etc. with the corresponding rows in DATASET1. The problem is I don't know how to combine these functions in order to make it work.

HERE IS A SAMPLE OF THE DATA I HAVE :

```
dataset1< - structure(list(country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L), .Label = c("Argentina", "Brazil", "France", "Japan", "Mexico", 
"Switzerland", "UK", "US"), class = "factor"), ID = 1:71, ideology = c(5L, 
9L, 4L, 8L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 
1L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 
7L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 9L, 4L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 9L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 9L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-71L)) 

dataset2 <- structure(list(country = structure(1:8, .Label = c("Argentina", 
"Brazil", "France", "Japan", "Mexico", "Switzerland", "UK", "US"
), class = "factor"), party_A.ID = c(1L, 10L, 25L, 37L, 43L, 
56L, 64L, 68L), party_B_ID = c(2L, 11L, 26L, 38L, 44L, 57L, 65L, 
69L), party_C_ID = c(3L, 12L, 27L, 39L, 47L, 58L, 66L, 70L), 
    party_D_ID = c(4L, 13L, 28L, 40L, 48L, 59L, 67L, 71L), party_E_ID = c(6L, 
    14L, 29L, NA, 49L, 60L, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

And here is the OUTPUT I want:

```
output <- structure(list(country = structure(1:8, .Label = c("Argentina", 
"Brazil", "France", "Japan", "Mexico", "Switzerland", "UK", "US"
), class = "factor"), party_A.ID = c(1L, 10L, 25L, 37L, 43L, 
56L, 64L, 68L), party_B_ID = c(2L, 11L, 26L, 38L, 44L, 57L, 65L, 
69L), party_C_ID = c(3L, 12L, 27L, 39L, 47L, 58L, 66L, 70L), 
    party_D_ID = c(4L, 13L, 28L, 40L, 48L, 59L, 67L, 71L), party_E_ID = c(6L, 
    14L, 29L, NA, 49L, 60L, NA, NA), other_party_1 = c(5L, 15L, 
    30L, 41L, 45L, 61L, NA, NA), other_party_2 = c(NA, 16L, 31L, 
    42L, 46L, 62L, NA, NA), other_party_3 = c(NA, 17L, 32L, NA, 
    50L, 63L, NA, NA), other_party_4 = c(NA, 18L, 33L, NA, 51L, 
    NA, NA, NA), other_party_5 = c(NA, 19L, 34L, NA, 52L, NA, 
    NA, NA), other_party_6 = c(NA, 20L, 35L, NA, 53L, NA, NA, 
    NA), other_party_7 = c(NA, 21L, 36L, NA, 54L, NA, NA, NA), 
    other_party_8 = c(NA, 22L, NA, NA, 55L, NA, NA, NA), other_party_9 = c(NA, 
    23L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), other_party_10 = c(NA, 24L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ideology_party_A = c(5L, 3L, 2L, 
    6L, 6L, 4L, 9L, 7L), ideology_party_B = c(9L, 0L, 5L, 4L, 
    5L, 9L, 4L, 3L), ideology_party_C = c(4L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 9L, 
    4L, 4L, 6L), ideology_party_D = c(8L, 2L, 0L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 
    1L, 6L), ideology_party_E = c(NA, 9L, 0L, NA, 0L, 1L, NA, 
    NA), ideology_other_party_1 = c(9L, 1L, 9L, 6L, 3L, 4L, NA, 
    NA), ideology_other_party_2 = c(NA, 7L, 8L, 3L, 7L, 7L, NA, 
    NA), ideology_other_party_3 = c(NA, 7L, 6L, NA, 0L, 7L, NA, 
    NA), ideology_other_party_4 = c(NA, 1L, 8L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 
    NA), ideology_other_party_5 = c(NA, 6L, 7L, NA, 0L, NA, NA, 
    NA), ideology_other_party_6 = c(NA, 6L, 7L, NA, 9L, NA, NA, 
    NA), ideology_other_party_7 = c(NA, 1L, 8L, NA, 4L, NA, NA, 
    NA), ideology_other_party_8 = c(NA, 1L, NA, NA, 8L, NA, NA, 
    NA), ideology_other_party_9 = c(NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), ideology_other_party_10 = c(NA, 8L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Notice the ID of parties in DATASET1 is in a sequence 1,2,3 ... but this sequence is not always followed when transponding to PARTY A-E. In fact, in my REAL data it is not even close to a sequence, I have 5-digit codes for each party. This is important, because I need a correct matching of each party in the rows of DATASET1 with the rows in DATASET2 based on the "ID" columns.

For the remaining parties (the columns with labels "other_party") it doesn't matter the order (which party will turn to be "other_party_1", "other_party_2", etc.), I just need these columns to be filled with data from parties that have not been considered in the variables labeled "Party A", "Party B", etc.

EDIT: the solutions presented in the answers worked fine for my example dataset, but with the REAL data I have they yield dozens of messy columns. Below a part of my original data. I did not delete the example dataset because I can't find a better way to express the output I desire.

```
dataset1 <- structure(list(election = c("SWE_1998", "SWE_1998", "SWE_1998", 
"SWE_1998", "SWE_1998", "SWE_1998", "SWE_1998", "SWE_2002", "SWE_2002", 
"SWE_2002", "SWE_2002", "SWE_2002", "SWE_2002", "SWE_2002", "SWE_2006", 
"SWE_2006", "SWE_2006", "SWE_2006", "SWE_2006", "SWE_2006", "SWE_2006", 
"SWE_2010", "SWE_2010", "SWE_2010", "SWE_2010", "SWE_2010", "SWE_2010", 
"SWE_2010", "SWE_2010", "SWE_2014", "SWE_2014", "SWE_2014", "SWE_2014", 
"SWE_2014", "SWE_2014", "SWE_2014", "SWE_2014", "SWE_2018", "SWE_2018", 
"SWE_2018", "SWE_2018", "SWE_2018", "SWE_2018", "SWE_2018", "SWE_2018", 
"NOR_1997", "NOR_1997", "NOR_1997", "NOR_1997", "NOR_1997", "NOR_1997", 
"NOR_1997", "NOR_2001", "NOR_2001", "NOR_2001", "NOR_2001", "NOR_2001", 
"NOR_2001", "NOR_2001", "NOR_2005", "NOR_2005", "NOR_2005", "NOR_2005", 
"NOR_2005", "NOR_2005", "NOR_2005", "NOR_2009", "NOR_2009", "NOR_2009", 
"NOR_2009", "NOR_2009", "NOR_2009", "NOR_2009", "NOR_2013", "NOR_2013", 
"NOR_2013", "NOR_2013", "NOR_2013", "NOR_2013", "NOR_2013", "NOR_2013", 
"NOR_2017", "NOR_2017", "NOR_2017", "NOR_2017", "NOR_2017", "NOR_2017", 
"NOR_2017", "NOR_2017", "NOR_2017", "DNK_1998", "DNK_1998", "DNK_1998", 
"DNK_1998", "DNK_1998", "DNK_1998", "DNK_1998", "DNK_1998", "DNK_1998", 
"DNK_1998", "DNK_2001", "DNK_2001", "DNK_2001", "DNK_2001", "DNK_2001", 
"DNK_2001", "DNK_2001", "DNK_2001", "DNK_2005", "DNK_2005", "DNK_2005", 
"DNK_2005", "DNK_2005", "DNK_2005", "DNK_2005", "DNK_2005", "DNK_2005", 
"DNK_2007", "DNK_2007", "DNK_2007", "DNK_2007", "DNK_2007", "DNK_2007", 
"DNK_2007", "DNK_2007", "DNK_2011", "DNK_2011", "DNK_2011", "DNK_2011", 
"DNK_2011", "DNK_2011", "DNK_2011", "DNK_2011", "DNK_2015", "DNK_2015", 
"DNK_2015", "DNK_2015", "DNK_2015", "DNK_2015", "DNK_2015", "DNK_2015", 
"DNK_2015", "DNK_2019", "DNK_2019", "DNK_2019", "DNK_2019", "DNK_2019", 
"DNK_2019", "DNK_2019", "DNK_2019", "DNK_2019", "DNK_2019", "FIN_1999", 
"FIN_1999", "FIN_1999", "FIN_1999", "FIN_1999", "FIN_1999", "FIN_1999", 
"FIN_1999", "FIN_2003", "FIN_2003", "FIN_2003", "FIN_2003", "FIN_2003", 
"FIN_2003", "FIN_2003", "FIN_2003", "FIN_2007", "FIN_2007", "FIN_2007", 
"FIN_2007", "FIN_2007", "FIN_2007", "FIN_2007", "FIN_2007", "FIN_2011", 
"FIN_2011", "FIN_2011", "FIN_2011", "FIN_2011", "FIN_2011", "FIN_2011", 
"FIN_2011", "FIN_2015", "FIN_2015", "FIN_2015", "FIN_2015", "FIN_2015", 
"FIN_2015", "FIN_2015", "FIN_2015", "FIN_2019", "FIN_2019", "FIN_2019", 
"FIN_2019", "FIN_2019", "FIN_2019", "FIN_2019", "FIN_2019", "FIN_2019", 
"ISL_1999", "ISL_1999", "ISL_1999", "ISL_1999", "ISL_1999", "ISL_2003", 
"ISL_2003", "ISL_2003", "ISL_2003", "ISL_2003", "ISL_2007", "ISL_2007", 
"ISL_2007", "ISL_2007", "ISL_2007", "ISL_2009", "ISL_2009", "ISL_2009", 
"ISL_2009", "ISL_2009", "ISL_2013", "ISL_2013", "ISL_2013", "ISL_2013", 
"ISL_2013", "ISL_2013", "ISL_2016", "ISL_2016", "ISL_2016", "ISL_2016", 
"ISL_2016", "ISL_2016", "ISL_2016", "ISL_2017", "ISL_2017", "ISL_2017", 
"ISL_2017", "ISL_2017", "ISL_2017", "ISL_2017", "ISL_2017", "ISL_2017", 
"BEL_1999", "BEL_1999", "BEL_1999", "BEL_1999", "BEL_1999", "BEL_1999", 
"BEL_1999", "BEL_1999", "BEL_1999", "BEL_1999", "BEL_2003", "BEL_2003", 
"BEL_2003", "BEL_2003", "BEL_2003", "BEL_2003", "BEL_2003", "BEL_2003", 
"BEL_2003", "BEL_2003", "BEL_2007", "BEL_2007", "BEL_2007", "BEL_2007", 
"BEL_2007", "BEL_2007", "BEL_2007", "BEL_2007", "BEL_2007", "BEL_2007", 
"BEL_2007", "BEL_2007", "BEL_2007", "BEL_2010", "BEL_2010", "BEL_2010", 
"BEL_2010", "BEL_2010", "BEL_2010", "BEL_2010", "BEL_2010", "BEL_2010", 
"BEL_2010", "BEL_2010", "BEL_2014", "BEL_2014", "BEL_2014", "BEL_2014", 
"BEL_2014", "BEL_2014", "BEL_2014", "BEL_2019", "BEL_2019", "BEL_2019", 
"BEL_2019", "BEL_2019", "BEL_2019"), ID = c(11110, 11220, 11320, 
11420, 11520, 11620, 11810, 11110, 11220, 11320, 11420, 11520, 
11620, 11810, 11110, 11220, 11320, 11420, 11520, 11620, 11810, 
11110, 11220, 11320, 11420, 11520, 11620, 11710, 11810, 11110, 
11220, 11320, 11420, 11520, 11620, 11710, 11810, 11110, 11220, 
11320, 11420, 11520, 11620, 11710, 11810, 12221, 12320, 12420, 
12520, 12620, 12810, 12951, 12221, 12320, 12420, 12520, 12620, 
12810, 12951, 12221, 12320, 12420, 12520, 12620, 12810, 12951, 
12221, 12320, 12420, 12520, 12620, 12810, 12951, 12110, 12221, 
12320, 12420, 12520, 12620, 12810, 12951, 12110, 12221, 12230, 
12320, 12420, 12520, 12620, 12810, 12951, 13229, 13230, 13320, 
13330, 13410, 13420, 13520, 13620, 13720, 13951, 13229, 13230, 
13320, 13410, 13420, 13520, 13620, 13720, 13229, 13230, 13320, 
13330, 13410, 13420, 13520, 13620, 13720, 13001, 13229, 13230, 
13320, 13410, 13420, 13620, 13720, 13001, 13229, 13230, 13320, 
13410, 13420, 13620, 13720, 13001, 13110, 13229, 13230, 13320, 
13410, 13420, 13620, 13720, 13001, 13110, 13229, 13230, 13320, 
13410, 13420, 13620, 13720, 13730, 14110, 14223, 14320, 14520, 
14620, 14810, 14820, 14901, 14110, 14223, 14320, 14520, 14620, 
14810, 14820, 14901, 14110, 14223, 14320, 14520, 14620, 14810, 
14820, 14901, 14110, 14223, 14320, 14520, 14620, 14810, 14820, 
14901, 14110, 14223, 14320, 14520, 14620, 14810, 14820, 14901, 
14110, 14223, 14320, 14440, 14520, 14620, 14810, 14820, 14901, 
15111, 15328, 15420, 15620, 15810, 15111, 15328, 15420, 15620, 
15810, 15111, 15328, 15420, 15620, 15810, 15111, 15328, 15430, 
15620, 15810, 15111, 15328, 15440, 15620, 15810, 15952, 15111, 
15328, 15440, 15450, 15620, 15810, 15952, 15111, 15328, 15440, 
15450, 15620, 15630, 15810, 15952, 15953, 21111, 21112, 21321, 
21322, 21421, 21425, 21521, 21522, 21914, 21915, 21111, 21112, 
21221, 21322, 21421, 21426, 21521, 21522, 21914, 21916, 21111, 
21112, 21221, 21321, 21322, 21330, 21421, 21426, 21430, 21521, 
21522, 21916, 21917, 21111, 21112, 21321, 21322, 21421, 21426, 
21430, 21521, 21522, 21916, 21917, 21112, 21230, 21321, 21421, 
21521, 21916, 21917, 21112, 21230, 21321, 21421, 21521, 21916
), ideology = c(-36.111, -35.952, -3.516, 14.286, 4.79, 37.425, 
11.57, -26.087, -33.661, -18.315, 0.932, 6.325, 38.061, 10.646, 
-11.616, -35.99, -24.173, 14.545, 0.806, 3.963, -4.459, -9.16, 
-12.205, -32.27, -4.803, 8.142, 2.479, 15.686, -2.24, -26.157, 
-33.889, -52.67, -2.523, 4.884, -16.748, -6.646, 7.895, -15.966, 
-40.701, -20, -1.144, -12.712, 7.562, -9.091, 9.978, -25.363, 
-18.112, -7.897, -4.549, 3.692, -10.553, 23.478, -44.022, -38.182, 
-15.502, -18.568, 9.789, -27.265, 23.963, -38.041, -33.293, -23.796, 
-24.37, 13.379, -17.608, 16.945, -40.106, -29.788, -18.531, -11.078, 
-11.405, -20.411, 6.763, -17.939, -28.267, -17.986, -15.495, 
-12.959, -9.011, -17.523, -1.945, -11.046, -28.961, -32.344, 
-29.793, -13.377, -12.328, -7.808, -16.705, 14.162, -32.479, 
-39.59, -1.042, -14.019, -5.455, 28.571, 43.21, 18.672, 9.722, 
34, -10.692, -33.846, -13.422, -3.774, 36.232, 24.675, 20.37, 
35, -42.152, -40.832, -36.332, -10.938, 0, -2.372, -3.883, 9.714, 
38, -12.5, -33.003, -37.143, -8.547, -9.615, -6.977, -17.355, 
14.894, 51.724, -41.778, -45.418, -6.509, -0.787, -13.717, 47.887, 
30.925, 28.704, -29.697, -46.429, -64.249, -2.091, 6.25, 17.822, 
60, 18.75, 15.534, -34.946, -38.182, -29.027, -18.437, -19.516, 
-17.483, -7.202, 32.979, 2.933, -6.25, -38.168, -1.37, 19.444, 
29.464, -1.049, -5.882, 14.516, -33.523, -45.946, -24.742, 7.813, 
9.756, -7.636, -5.882, -19.931, -21.471, -42.051, -36.432, -15.108, 
-20.556, -15.09, -6.518, -25.472, -27.715, -44.767, -11.384, 
-16.771, 13.75, -16.383, 0.472, -23.392, -37.05, -42.781, -27.016, 
4.967, -12.535, -4.348, -4.936, -20.865, -38.601, -41.021, -23.413, 
-32.222, -9.481, 1.2, -21.687, -13.809, -14.199, -32.5, -19.38, 
5.505, 18.182, -9.767, -22.222, -21.801, 15.556, 3.797, -11.558, 
-23.188, -24.286, -0.617, 3.797, -15.086, 1.389, -10, -1.613, 
39.506, -7.895, -32.71, -11.017, -6.633, 13.445, -17.094, -40, 
-29.679, -27.073, -15.205, -11.207, 8.916, -6.25, -23.022, -28.625, 
-30.189, -14.706, -11.207, -0.628, NA, -55, -26.104, -41.333, 
-19.763, -16.68, -1.429, -14.869, 5.556, -7.805, -4.185, -11.928, 
-2.997, -6.612, -17.336, -21.575, -13.571, -25.309, 0.373, -29.641, 
1.869, -12.133, -2.997, -7.576, -20.32, -3.753, -3.646, -26.752, 
-32.261, -17.939, 13.488, -20.861, 33.782, 11.393, -26.769, 27.51, 
24.571, -31.299, -0.855, -12.609, -26.688, 12.726, -0.2, 41.463, 
7.248, -24.555, 11.691, 39.443, -18.063, -34.785, -15.502, -3.859, 
-0.102, 8.584, 17.3, -21.849, -33.681, -19.199, -8, -11.903, 
4.78)), row.names = c(NA, -300L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))


dataset2 <- structure(list(election = c("ALB_2005", "ARG_2015", "AUS_1996", 
"AUS_2004", "AUS_2007", "AUS_2013", "AUT_2008", "AUT_2013", "BLR_2001", 
"BLR_2008", "BEL_2003", "BELF1999", "BELW1999", "BRA_2002", "BRA_2006", 
"BRA_2010", "BRA_2014", "BGR_2001", "BGR_2014", "CAN_1997", "CAN_2004", 
"CAN_2008", "CAN_2011", "CAN_2015", "CHL_1999", "CHL_2005", "CHL_2009", 
"HRV_2007", "CZE_1996", "CZE_2002", "CZE_2006", "CZE_2010", "CZE_2013", 
"DNK_1998", "DNK_2001", "DNK_2007", "EST_2011", "FIN_2003", "FIN_2007", 
"FIN_2011", "FIN_2015", "FRA_2002", "FRA_2007", "FRA_2012", "DEU_1998", 
"DEU_2005", "DEU_2009", "DEU_2013", "DEU12002", "DEU22002", "GBR_1997", 
"GBR_2005", "GBR_2015", "GRC_2009", "GRC_2012", "GRC_2015", "HKG_1998", 
"HKG_2000", "HKG_2004", "HKG_2008", "HKG_2012", "HUN_1998", "HUN_2002", 
"ISL_1999", "ISL_2003", "ISL_2007", "ISL_2009", "ISL_2013", "IRL_2002", 
"IRL_2007", "IRL_2011", "ISR_1996", "ISR_2003", "ISR_2006", "ISR_2013", 
"ITA_2006", "JPN_1996", "JPN_2004", "JPN_2007", "JPN_2013", "KEN_2013", 
"KGZ_2005", "LVA_2010", "LVA_2011", "LVA_2014", "LTU_1997", "MEX_1997", 
"MEX_2000", "MEX_2003", "MEX_2006", "MEX_2009", "MEX_2012", "MEX_2015", 
"MNE_2012", "NLD_1998", "NLD_2002", "NLD_2006", "NLD_2010", "NZL_1996", 
"NZL_2002", "NZL_2008", "NZL_2011", "NZL_2014", "NOR_1997", "NOR_2001", 
"NOR_2005", "NOR_2009", "NOR_2013", "PER_2000", "PER_2001", "PER_2006", 
"PER_2011", "PER_2016", "PHL_2004", "PHL_2010", "PHL_2016", "POL_1997", 
"POL_2001", "POL_2005", "POL_2007", "POL_2011", "PRT_2002", "PRT_2005", 
"PRT_2009", "PRT_2015", "KOR_2000", "KOR_2004", "KOR_2008", "KOR_2012", 
"ROU_1996", "ROU_2004", "ROU_2009", "ROU_2012", "ROU_2014", "RUS_1999", 
"RUS_2000", "RUS_2004", "SRB_2012", "SVK_2010", "SVK_2016", "SVN_1996", 
"SVN_2004", "SVN_2008", "SVN_2011", "ZAF_2009", "ZAF_2014", "ESP_1996", 
"ESP_2000", "ESP_2004", "ESP_2008", "SWE_1998", "SWE_2002", "SWE_2006", 
"SWE_2014", "CHE_1999", "CHE_2003", "CHE_2007", "CHE_2011", "TWN_1996", 
"TWN_2001", "TWN_2004", "TWN_2008", "TWN_2012", "THA_2001", "THA_2007", 
"THA_2011", "TUR_2011", "TUR_2015", "UKR_1998", "USA_1996", "USA_2004", 
"USA_2008", "USA_2012", "URY_2009"), party_ID_A = c(75624, 999999, 
63320, 63620, 63320, 63620, 42320, 42320, 78211, 78211, 21421, 
999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 80902, 80510, 
62420, 62420, 62623, 62623, 62420, 999999, 999999, 999999, 81711, 
82413, 82320, 82413, 82320, 82320, 13320, 13420, 13420, 83430, 
14810, 14810, 14620, 14810, 31625, 31626, 31320, 41320, 41320, 
41521, 41521, 41320, 41320, 51320, 51320, 51620, 34313, 34511, 
34212, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 86220, 86220, 
15620, 15620, 15620, 999999, 15620, 53620, 53620, 53520, 72323, 
72622, 72430, 999999, 32610, 71620, 71624, 71624, 71620, 999999, 
999999, 87062, 87021, 87340, 999999, 171301, 171601, 171601, 
171601, 171301, 171301, 171301, 91020, 22320, 22521, 22521, 22420, 
64620, 64320, 64620, 64620, 64620, 12320, 12320, 12320, 12320, 
12320, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
999999, 92620, 92212, 92436, 92435, 92435, 35313, 35311, 35311, 
35060, 113630, 113422, 113630, 113630, 93411, 93222, 93530, 93031, 
999999, 94221, 94221, 94951, 95070, 96423, 96423, 97421, 97330, 
97322, 97340, 181310, 181310, 33610, 33610, 33320, 33320, 11320, 
11320, 11320, 11320, 43810, 43810, 43810, 43810, 999999, 999999, 
999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 74628, 74628, 
98221, 61320, 61620, 61320, 61320, 999999), party_ID_B = c(75220, 
999999, 63620, 63320, 63620, 63320, 42520, 42520, 78212, 78212, 
21221, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 80411, 
80221, 62621, 62623, 62420, 62320, 62623, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
81220, 82320, 82413, 82320, 82413, 82430, 13420, 13320, 13320, 
83411, 14320, 14620, 14320, 14620, 31720, 31320, 31626, 41521, 
41521, 41320, 41320, 41521, 41521, 51620, 51620, 51320, 34511, 
34212, 34511, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 86421, 
86421, 999999, 999999, 999999, 15620, 15810, 53520, 53520, 53320, 
72622, 72323, 72323, 72440, 32220, 71623, 71620, 71620, 71624, 
999999, 999999, 87021, 87620, 87062, 999999, 171601, 171301, 
171301, 171305, 171601, 171601, 171601, 91060, 22420, 22720, 
22320, 22320, 64320, 64620, 64320, 64320, 64320, 12951, 12620, 
12951, 12951, 12620, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
999999, 999999, 999999, 92210, 92435, 92435, 92436, 92436, 35311, 
35313, 35313, 35311, 113430, 113630, 113440, 113440, 93223, 93430, 
93002, 93061, 999999, 94620, 94620, 94221, 95430, 96523, 96440, 
97521, 97421, 97330, 97330, 181411, 181411, 33320, 33320, 33610, 
33610, 11620, 11620, 11620, 11620, 43320, 43320, 43320, 43320, 
999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
74321, 74321, 98611, 61620, 61320, 61620, 61620, 999999), party_ID_C = c(75722, 
999999, 63810, 63110, 63810, 63110, 42420, 42420, 999999, 999999, 
21521, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 80220, 
80951, 62620, 62320, 62901, 62420, 62320, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
81712, 82220, 82220, 82220, 82530, 82220, 13620, 13720, 13720, 
83611, 14620, 14320, 14820, 14820, 31320, 31624, 31720, 41521, 
41420, 41420, 41223, 41521, 41521, 51421, 51421, 51951, 34210, 
34313, 34720, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 86810, 
86422, 15810, 15810, 15111, 15111, 999999, 53320, 53320, 53620, 
72533, 72413, 72533, 72323, 32710, 71624, 999999, 999999, 71220, 
999999, 999999, 87110, 87062, 87110, 88621, 171305, 171031, 171305, 
171301, 171305, 171305, 171305, 91224, 22521, 22420, 22220, 22722, 
64621, 64621, 64110, 64110, 64110, 12620, 12951, 12620, 12620, 
12951, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
999999, 92434, 92622, 92622, 92021, 92440, 35520, 35229, 35520, 
35211, 113650, 113320, 113651, 113321, 93322, 93221, 93430, 93981, 
999999, 94622, 94622, 94711, 95221, 96440, 96620, 97320, 97322, 
97440, 97322, 181420, 181210, 33220, 33220, 33220, 33611, 11220, 
11420, 11810, 11710, 43420, 43420, 43420, 43420, 999999, 999999, 
999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 74712, 74712, 
98321, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999), party_ID_D = c(75320, 
999999, 63321, 63810, 63110, 63410, 42710, 42110, 999999, 999999, 
21322, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 80951, 
80061, 62320, 62901, 62320, 62901, 62901, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
81810, 82523, 82523, 82523, 82220, 82530, 13230, 13620, 13230, 
83410, 14223, 14223, 14810, 14320, 31624, 31720, 31021, 41113, 
41222, 41223, 41113, 41113, 41113, 51902, 51902, 51421, 34710, 
34730, 34340, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 86422, 
86620, 15111, 15111, 15810, 15810, 15111, 53951, 53110, 53951, 
72530, 72533, 72622, 72701, 32421, 71220, 71220, 71220, 999999, 
999999, 999999, 87071, 87071, 87071, 88320, 171101, 171306, 171101, 
171101, 171101, 171101, 171210, 91330, 22330, 22320, 22420, 22521, 
64321, 64420, 64621, 64621, 64621, 12520, 12221, 12221, 12221, 
12520, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
999999, 92811, 92436, 92210, 92811, 92811, 35229, 35520, 35211, 
35229, 999999, 113430, 999999, 113651, 93951, 93712, 93712, 93951, 
93981, 94621, 94621, 999999, 95712, 96521, 96710, 97520, 97522, 
97951, 97450, 181910, 181910, 33611, 33611, 33611, 33902, 11520, 
11520, 11420, 11110, 43520, 43520, 43520, 43520, 999999, 999999, 
999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 74325, 74210, 
98111, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999), party_ID_E = c(999999, 
999999, 63110, 999999, 999999, 63810, 42110, 42710, 999999, 999999, 
21914, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
80062, 62901, 62110, 62110, 62110, 62110, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
81957, 82710, 999999, 82110, 82952, 82413, 13720, 13230, 13620, 
83612, 999999, 999999, 14223, 999999, 999999, 31220, 31624, 41420, 
41113, 41113, 41521, 41420, 41420, 51901, 51901, 51902, 34020, 
34720, 34210, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 86620, 
999999, 15420, 15420, 15420, 15430, 15440, 53420, 53951, 53021, 
72326, 72624, 72625, 72533, 32530, 71320, 71320, 71320, 71430, 
999999, 999999, 87061, 87110, 87630, 999999, 171306, 171101, 
171306, 171306, 171306, 171306, 171101, 91920, 22110, 22110, 
22722, 22220, 64420, 64110, 64420, 999999, 999999, 12810, 12520, 
12520, 12810, 12810, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
999999, 999999, 999999, 92621, 92811, 92713, 999999, 92210, 35211, 
35211, 35229, 35120, 113620, 113650, 113320, 999999, 93712, 93951, 
93951, 93712, 93712, 999999, 999999, 94621, 95431, 96955, 96720, 
97321, 97521, 97710, 97951, 999999, 999999, 33902, 33902, 33905, 
33905, 11810, 11220, 11520, 11810, 43110, 43110, 43110, 43110, 
999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
74717, 74717, 98426, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999), 
    party_ID_F = c(999999, 999999, 999999, 63321, 999999, 999999, 
    42421, 42430, 999999, 999999, 21426, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 80630, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 81713, 82412, 999999, 
    999999, 82523, 82720, 13330, 13410, 13410, 83110, 14520, 
    14901, 999999, 14223, 999999, 31110, 31110, 41221, 41521, 
    41521, 41420, 41221, 41221, 999999, 999999, 51110, 999999, 
    34213, 34730, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    86521, 999999, 999999, 15328, 15420, 15952, 53110, 53420, 
    53110, 999999, 72326, 72530, 72535, 32212, 71951, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 87422, 999999, 87901, 999999, 
    171304, 171303, 171311, 171311, 171309, 171309, 171311, 999999, 
    22220, 22220, 22110, 22330, 999999, 64421, 64901, 64901, 
    64902, 12221, 12810, 12810, 12520, 12420, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 92322, 92713, 
    92811, 999999, 999999, 999999, 35220, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 113321, 93711, 93001, 999999, 999999, 93951, 
    94422, 94422, 94422, 95451, 96710, 96725, 97951, 97710, 999999, 
    97521, 999999, 999999, 33907, 999999, 33902, 33220, 11420, 
    11810, 11220, 11220, 43531, 999999, 43530, 43530, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 98810, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999), party_ID_G = c(75810, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 42951, 78710, 
    999999, 21522, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 80710, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 81410, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 82523, 
    999999, 13229, 13001, 999999, 14901, 14520, 14901, 14901, 
    31110, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 41953, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 51901, 999999, 34210, 34313, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 72431, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 71111, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 87422, 999999, 88420, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    171309, 171311, 171311, 171309, 999999, 22527, 22330, 22526, 
    22110, 999999, 64422, 64422, 64902, 64901, 999999, 12420, 
    12420, 12420, 12221, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 92620, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 35110, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 113321, 999999, 
    93430, 999999, 999999, 93222, 999999, 999999, 999999, 94222, 
    95711, 96952, 96955, 97710, 97951, 97421, 97522, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 33907, 33908, 999999, 11110, 11110, 
    11420, 999999, 999999, 43531, 43901, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 74626, 999999, 98427, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999), party_ID_H = c(75421, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 42220, 999999, 
    999999, 21916, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 80330, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 81952, 999999, 999999, 999999, 82110, 82110, 
    999999, 13520, 13229, 999999, 999999, 14820, 14520, 14520, 
    999999, 31630, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 41952, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 72326, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 71320, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 88220, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    171310, 171310, 999999, 171611, 999999, 999999, 22526, 22330, 
    22526, 999999, 64321, 64421, 64420, 64420, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 12110, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 92434, 999999, 999999, 92953, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 35520, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 93521, 999999, 93430, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    95902, 96711, 96630, 999999, 999999, 97522, 97710, 999999, 
    181420, 999999, 999999, 33908, 999999, 999999, 999999, 11710, 
    11520, 999999, 999999, 43901, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 74621, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999), party_ID_I = c(999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 21111, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 81953, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 82953, 
    999999, 13330, 13520, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    31220, 31230, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 72901, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 171306, 999999, 999999, 22952, 22952, 
    22952, 999999, 999999, 999999, 64421, 64421, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 92322, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 93530, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 96220, 96521, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 33440, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 74324, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999)), row.names = c(NA, 
-174L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

PS: I don't need information on "elections" (i.e., country/year) that are not included in dataset2, in case that helps in anyway to find a better code.

Comment: In `dataset1` I find 9 parties (ID1 to 9) for Argentina, whereas I only find 6 parties (ID1 to 6) in `output`. Is it accidental or intentional?

Comment: It is intentional. The parties are not always the same, not in the same order and even the "countries" are not correspondent in my real dataset (in fact the real dataset has country/years,  not just countries).

Comment: How do you define which parties to drop from the output which are not included in parties A-E (for Argentina's case, ID7-9 are dropped out)? Actually, this drop-out is found only for Argentina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can specify several key columns as `by` argument in `join` function.
Accordingly, the following code would provide the expected output.

```r
output <- dataset1 %>% left_join(dataset2 %>% pivot_longer(cols=-country, values_to="ID"), by=c("country", "ID")) %>%
  arrange(country, name) %>% nest(data=-country) %>% mutate(data=map(data, function(data){
    data %>% filter(is.na(name)) %>% mutate(name=str_c("other_party_", row_number())) %>%
      bind_rows(data %>% filter(!is.na(name)), .) %>% return()
  })) %>% unnest(cols=data) %>% pivot_longer(cols=c(ID, ideology), names_to="type") %>% arrange(type) %>%
  mutate(name=if_else(type=="ID", name, str_c(type, "_", str_replace(name, ".ID", ""))) %>% as_factor()) %>%
  select(-type) %>% pivot_wider()
```

**UPDATE:**
In your real dataset, I found several `election` items that are only in `dataset1` (ex. `BEL_1999`) or only in `dataset2` (ex. `BELF1999`). Then you should use `full_join` instead of `left_join` to keep all items.
And I suppose that `999999` in `dataset2` should be converted to NAs beforehand.

Accordingly, the following code would work fine.

```r
dataset1 %>% full_join(dataset2 %>% pivot_longer(cols=-election, values_to="ID"), by=c("election", "ID")) %>%
  arrange(election, name) %>% nest(data=-election) %>% mutate(data=map(data, function(data){
    data %>% filter(is.na(name)) %>% mutate(name=str_c("other_party_", row_number())) %>%
      bind_rows(data %>% filter(!is.na(name)), .) %>% return()
  })) %>% unnest(cols=data) %>% pivot_longer(cols=c(ID, ideology), names_to="type") %>% arrange(type) %>%
  mutate(name=if_else(type=="ID", name, str_c(type, "_", str_replace(name, "_ID", ""))) %>% as_factor(),
         value=if_else(value==999999, NA_real_, value)) %>%
  select(-type) %>% pivot_wider() %>%
  select(election, starts_with("party"), starts_with("other"),
         starts_with("ideology_party"), starts_with("ideology_other"))
```

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for taking so long to answer. I was trying to understand all the outputs here. It does work properly with the fake data, but in my real dataset it is not working properly. For the subset I described above, it correctly brings data from dataset1 for "party_A_ideology", etc. but it does not bring the additional ones (those that were not matched in "party_ID and were supposed to be included as "other_party_1", etc. 

 Please see the EDIT where I included code to the a sample of the real data.

Comment: @GuilhermePiresArbache I updated my answer. If it does not work well, please provide your expected output, or indicate for which specific `election`s and `ID`s are not correct.

Comment: Thanks for all efforts. 

It works perfectly with both examples of datasets I gave above, the fake ones and the sample of the real ones I have (which is 30% of "real" dataset1 and the complete version of "real" dataset2). But it still yields a messy dataset when I try with the whole data: hundreds of columns for "other parties", and, if that helps you anyway: some of these columns with "unknown" class and a warning message:`Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.`

Comment: It might have something to do with the "full join". As I wrote in my last EDIT, I do not need ELECTIONS not included in dataset2 (but I do need PARTIES that are from dataset1 if they are in elections included in dataset2 - these would be the "other parties). But I'm not sure WHY having many "elections" here yields this mess.

Nevertheless, I tried your code with a cleaner version of dataset1 including just elections from dataset2, which is what I need ( (841 rows). It seems to yield the desired output in terms of columns, but still with that warning message and "unkown" class.

Comment: Therefore, for my practical use, I guess I had it right now thanks to your code. But maybe I should edit the question - deleting the fake data and making it clearer what is the desired output and what is going on wrong?

Comment: What is very odd here is that I have a few columns in the end that I just can't change from "unknown" class to other (I was changing first to character so then I could change them to "numeric").

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. The warning probably comes from `pivot_wider`. It might be helpful if you could provide `dataset1` only for `election`s that are not working well (those that have non-null data in columns of "unknown" class).

Comment: I can share a sample, maybe "clean" the question since I've reached the maximum of characters. Anyway, I've found out I had some parties that were duplicated (i.e., same ID for the same election) since there are cases with two elections in the same country, same year. After solving for that the warnings were gone. I just have the final columns still as "unknown" (these are columns for "ideology_other_party" from 8 to 13, which are not NA just for ONE election. Still not sure the reason, but it is all fine. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe just changing `dataset1 %>% full_join(dataset2 %>% pivot_longer(...` to `dataset1 %>% full_join(dataset2 %>% mutate(i=row_number()) %>% pivot_longer(...` will work fine? Anyway glad to hear that you managed to get a good result :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you can try correcting the `ID` number for each `country` in  `dataset1` and get data in wide format and then join it with `dataset2`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dataset1 %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(ID = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = ID, values_from = ideology, names_prefix = 'ideology') %>%
  inner_join(dataset2, by = 'country') -> result

result
```

Comment: It is not possible. As I said in the bottom, the indexes are not in a sequence 1,2,3, they are party codes of 5 digit. I just put this way to make it simpler in the example. Correcting all IDs would take me forever. That is the problem.

Comment: I am not correcting the ID's manually in my answer though. So I am not sure what exactly is the problem.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. But for some reason the codes are not working properly with my real datasets. I am trying to figure out what is different from the example datasets I provided above.

Comment: Probably, you need to share a better representation of your data or share the subset of your actual data.

Comment: Yes, I know. I was just trying to make things easier but I guess it was the opposite. Please see the edit above with a sample from the real dataset. Would it help if I just edit the whole question with a part of the real data and the desired output , and delete the fake data?

Comment: @GuilhermePiresArbache My answer still works for your updated data as well. Just need to replace `country` with `election`. It atleast works for me without any error. What does it give you?

Comment: The same problem as always. The code does work, no warnings or errors, but the output is a lot of "ideology" columns (ideology1, 2, etc.) and it loses the match of ID between dataset 1 and dataset2. If it only hasn't lost the IDs, I could use something like case_when to create variables such as "ideology_party_A", etc. for the ones that have an ID provided in dataset2. That is very important because I need to compare this data with other data about these parties.